# Why couldn't I cache a variable in MULE4?

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mulesoft, mule4

Im trying to cache a varibale in mule4. My simple test caching  flow is this;

```
<ee:object-store-caching-strategy name="Caching_Strategy" doc:name="Caching Strategy" doc:id="9c17681c-81c3-4344-bd4f-7fda1e36a440">
        <os:private-object-store alias="token" persistent="false" entryTtl="100" expirationInterval="5" />
    </ee:object-store-caching-strategy>
<ee:cache doc:name="Cache" doc:id="b413ab46-e3e1-4eb0-ac40-0e5884e1438f" cachingStrategy-ref="Caching_Strategy">

            <set-variable value="500" doc:name="Set Variable" doc:id="97f4436c-98d3-4993-a4bc-b191282b8f16" variableName="cachevariable"/>
            <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" doc:id="0a88f98d-ace9-4326-8d84-31fb7030b75a" message="inside cache"/>

        </ee:cache>
<logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" doc:id="d92550c2-041f-42ae-b3b5-62ea906ccbb0" message="#[vars.'cachevariable']"/>
```

In the above scenario i try to cache a variable named **cachevariable**
In first invocation. my cache flow get hits and the log outside cache scope prints 500.
In the second invocation within a minute, i get Null for `cachevariable`.

Why is that?

I use anypointstudio 7.5.1 with runtime 4.1.3

Answer (score 0):

I have used the caching strategy with a reference to an object store instead of using a private one:

```
<os:object-store name="customObjectStore" persistent="false" entryTtl="15" expirationInterval="15" expirationIntervalUnit="SECONDS" maxEntries="100"/>
<ee:object-store-caching-strategy  name="Caching_Strategy" doc:name="Caching Strategy" objectStore="customObjectStore" keyGenerationExpression="#[vars.id]" />
```

Also I recommend to always set the maxEntries.

My example is on my blog: https://medium.com/@adobni/configuring-an-object-store-in-mule-4-5da609e3456a